# stored procedure is execution taking long time in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-performance

I have a table called Transaction_tbl with more than 400 000 records in it. This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction_tbl](
    [transactID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TBarcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [cmpid] [int] NULL,
    [Locid] [int] NULL,
    [PSID] [int] NULL,
    [PCID] [int] NULL,
    [PCdID] [int] NULL,
    [PlateNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [vtid] [int] NULL,
    [Compl] [bit] NULL,
    [self] [bit] NULL,
    [LstTic] [bit] NULL,
    [Gticket] [int] NULL,
    [Cticket] [int] NULL,
    [Ecode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dtime] [datetime] NULL,
    [LICID] [int] NULL,
    [PAICID] [int] NULL,
    [Plot] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [mkid] [int] NULL,
    [mdlid] [int] NULL,
    [Colid] [int] NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Kticket] [int] NULL,
    [PAmount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Payid] [int] NULL,
    [Paid] [bit] NULL,
    [Paydate] [datetime] NULL,
    [POICID] [int] NULL,
    [DelDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DelEcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PAICdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [KeyRoomDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction_tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [transactID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have a nonclustered index on the Locid, dtime column.
I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreleasedinpodiumgridnew]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
Declare @krrt integer
Declare @DT integer
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-1



SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode,cast(t.Paydate as Time) [REQ],
       datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
                WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                WHEN 4 THEN t.KeyRoomDate
                When 5 THEN  t.KeyRoomDate
                End) as KRRT,

             datediff(MINUTE,t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
              WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
              WHEN 4 THEN GETDATE()
             WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
             END) as DT

   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t

   WHERE   

   ( 
       ([status] IN (3,4))
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, DelDate, GETDATE()) <= 3)
   )
   AND locid = 6 AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days
   ORDER BY  
       paydate 
       end
```

my execution plan like this:
[image]

but most of the time this is taking long time to execute ..in this case how i can improve my stored procedure execution performance?
any other method i want to use..any help is very appriciable.Thanks

the query execution plan is showing sorting is taking long time..so if i give index on `paydate` my query performance will increase?
instead of this `dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days` i given code like this:

```
dtime >= OPTION (optimize for (@TodayMinus7Days))
```

but getting error:**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.**

Comment: sort is taking longest time as can be seen from query plan.

Comment: To me; `ORDER BY  paydate` is the culprit here. Try creating an index on paydate (OR) use an indexed column in order by

Comment: Is there something you're not showing us? This plan suggests an inner join that shouldn't exist.

Comment: 1) What "does  more than 4 lack records in it" mean. 2) Roughly how many rows are you returning when it is "slow". 3) How slow? e.g, 2 secs. 20 min, etc. 4) Why is @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-1. 5) Have you tried WITH (INDEX (Your_Locid_dtime_Index))
  6) Have you tried a hint similar to  "option (optimize for (`@TodayMinus7Days = '2000-01-01'`))"

Comment: After I while, I think I can guess that your select is probably using the your Locid_dtime index -- though the query plan picture does not show this for sure -- If you only have the PK and the 1 index you mention, it is be using the index that I suggested in the hint.

Comment: Your query plan in not the query plan the the stored proc. Get a query plan on "exec IBS_fetchreleasedinpodiumgridnew"

Comment: when ever returning more than 20 rows,this getting slow..around 30 second it s taking to execute?

Comment: getdate()-1 means taking last 24 hours data from Table

Comment: if i declared this... OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TodayMinus7Days UNKNOWN))..what is the use of that

Answer (score 6):

Apart from optimizing the query, there are a couple things I can immediately suggest to improve the performance of a stored procedure.

**Parameter sniffing**: When the store procedure is passed a parameter, it analyses the dataset to figure out what would be the most efficient indexes. This is useful, though the plan is cached, and will get out of date, causing the stored proc to run on an inefficient execution plan.

Solution: Re-declare parameters or optimize the stored proc for unknown parameter values

**Suppress the row count**: One of the most simple things you can do to increase the performance of a stored procedure is SET NOCOUNT ON. This will prevent SQL Server from sending messages back to the client after the execution of each statement, which is not required for a stored proc. It seems like a small improvement, but the results are noticeable.

Solution: SET NOCOUNT ON

The snippet below has an example of where they go in your stored proc. Note that if you are re-declaring parameters, you don't need to optimize for unknown, and vice versa.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.example_proc   
(   
    @USER_PARAM VARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- suppress  the number of rows returned
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Re-declaring the variable will prevent paramater sniffing
    DECLARE @LOCAL_USER_PARAM VARCHAR(200) = @USER_PARAM

    SELECT
        *
    FROM some_table st
    WHERE st.some_column = @LOCAL_USER_PARAM

    -- If you don't re-declare params, you can add this line
    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@USER_PARAM UNKNOWN))
    --

END 
GO
```

Comment: what you mean by Re-declare parameters or optimize the stored proc for unknown parameter values

Comment: i given like this dtime >= OPTION (optimize for (@TodayMinus7Days))..but getting error

Comment: You use the parameters as normal in your query, then add the line OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TodayMinus7Days UNKNOWN)) down the bottom

Comment: why you specifying UNKNOWN

Comment: if i declared this...  OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TodayMinus7Days UNKNOWN))..what is the use of that

Comment: SQL server will compile the stored proc with an execution plan, etc. which is optimized for specific values. By telling it to optimize for unknown, this tells it to not use a pre-prepared execution plan which may be out of date, and optimized for different values.

Comment: Correct. The performance increase will change will be different for each stored proc, depending on execution plan, indexing and especially, where it is being called from.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "with recompile" to get more suitable execution plan based on parameter. In my case it help reduce time from about 1 hours to a few minutes. Hope it work in your case as well.

```
exec [dbo].[IBS_fetchreleasedinpodiumgridnew] 1 with recompile
```

Answer (score -1):

Check By Manually run the SP. If it is working fine than your problem is isolation level.
add these line in store procedure beginning.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED  ;
```