# execution of stored procedure taking long time when ever returning row count hig

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-performance

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreleasedinpodiumgridnew]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-7

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode,
       cast(t.Paydate as Time) [REQ],
       datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
                CASE t.Status
                   WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                   WHEN 4 THEN t.KeyRoomDate
                   WHEN 5 THEN  t.KeyRoomDate
                END) as KRRT,
       datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
                CASE t.Status
                   WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                   WHEN 4 THEN GETDATE()
                   WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
                END) as DT
   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
      (([status] IN (3,4))
      OR 
      ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, DelDate, GETDATE()) <= 3)
      )
      AND locid = 6 
      AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days
   ORDER BY  
       paydate 
end
```

I have a nonclustered index on the `Locid, dtime` columns.

My table has more than 4 lack records.. whenever returning more than 25 rows this is taking a long time to execute (sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes 45 seconds). Why this is happening? How can I execute my stored procedure faster?

Someone suggested to add this code

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TodayMinus7Days UNKNOWN))
```

at the end of this stored procedure... if I add this my execution performance will increase? What is the use of this code? What all are the other optimization I have to do in this stored procedure?

Any help is appreciated!

this is the my query execution plan

[image]

Comment: there could be numerous reasons why it could be slow. showing your schema and an execution plan would help people diagnose issues, otherwise there's not enough information here to provide an answer

Comment: i want to take stored procedure execution plan or this sql query execution plan

Comment: either will do as they will both execute the same query

Comment: ok,,,i will edit my question with query exxecution plan

Comment: sir i edited my question with query execution plan..

Comment: if i declared this... OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TodayMinus7Days UNKNOWN))..what is the use of this???

Comment: I've never used that, perhaps ask whoever told you that to explain?

Comment: in this link they answered like that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617577/stored-procedure-is-execution-taking-long-time-in-sql-server

Comment: you should extend the previous question rather than ask a question that mirrors your other question

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "optimize for" is not unreasonable.
The idea is to tell the db engine not to assume the first date value used with this proc is typical when making the execution plan.

But your execution plan is so simple, with just one table, I expect that hint may not be an answer.

The execution plan shows 2 things.

First, the slowest thing is the Sort == your Order By.
Sorts are always slow and don't scale well.
If by any chance you don't really need it, removing the Order By will make the most impact.
If you really do need the Order By, the only way to eliminate the Sort would be adding an index on the Order By column... and using it.
As with any index decision, you have to weigh the pros and cons of adding it.

And that leads to the other operation -  the key lookup.
You have two steps to the data pull, the index seek, and then the key lookup for all the columns you want.
You could eliminate the key lookup by making your index Include all the needed columns (or create such an index new).
Again, you should weigh the pros and cons of the index change in your system.